# Switched a outdoor gfci for a working one but now other components in the house don't work?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci

I did some minor electrical work for a friend as I have some minor electrical knowledge myself, and he called me today saying that the heated floor and towel warmers are not working since I swapped out his old broken outdoor GFCI for a new working one.

The outdoor receptacle had 2 blacks, 2 whites, a ground, and is being powered from 2 breakers (3 and 7). There was a black on the top and bottom and same with the neutrals on the other side so I put everything exactly as it was already and added a ground wire to ground the box as well. The GFCI works and provides power still (as far as I'm aware).

My best guess would be to maybe try putting everything in the top half but with it being 2 breakers I'm not sure if I should do that.

Does any one have any advice on how I should go about this or what's causing it?

Comment: What makes you think it was powered from two breakers? Something is seriously messed up there...

Comment: GFCIs don't have a top and bottom.  They have a LINE and LOAD, that's what matters!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it was powered from 2 breakers cause one of the blacks lost power with breaker 7 and the other lost power with breaker 3(found that out the hard way).

Comment: The gfci still has a top plug and a bottom plug not really sure how to describe it other wise power from 1 breaker goes into the top half and power from another breaker goes into the bottom half and then theres 2 neutral wires coming out from the other side all i did was pop off one gfci and out on a new one and grounded the box

Comment: @Soren -- yeah, it sounds like you've unearthed signs of a bigger mess here. Can you figure out what other things are on the two circuits in question?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel to an extent i know breaker 3 controls the mudroom lights and living room lights, modem plug and lamp plug as well. Im not looking to do extensive work on this as i really dont have the skill set i did a year of school and 6 months in the field till covid hit. Im hoping to be able to wrap this all up in just that box hopefully at the very least get it back to its status quo with hopefully a working gfci in place. Do you have some where i could message you more frequently/directly so we could maybe discuss fixes and options (if you have any)

Comment: @Soren -- not really, external contact isn't part of the Stack model.

Comment: YIKES.   its a very bad idea to do electrical work for a friend if you are not licensed (and not allowed!)  Oddly you can do your own though (my wife laughs at me on this as I wire up my own 400Amp shop...)

Comment: It may have originally been a non-GFCI outlet wired to 2 circuits, then someone "improved" safety by replacing it with a GFCI wired exactly the same way (so they thought). Backfeeding power into the LOAD side eventually fried the GFCI, leading to the replacement you made and a more immediate failure with a more modern GFCI. I'm all for DIY, but your friend may need to call in an electrician on this one to get it sorted out safely & to code.

Answer (score 2):

### For now: cap off breaker 7's hot and neutral in the panel

What you discovered with two breakers feeding power to the two sides of a GFCI is something that basically shouldn't have ever happened to begin with; GFCIs aren't meant to have power backfed onto their LOAD terminals, even, as that can fry older units, and will cause new GFCIs to "lock out".  Fixing it properly will require quite a bit of detective work (I suspect that the two circuits' hots got joined together inadvertently somewhere), but there is a way out of the jam for now.

What I'd do in this situation to get the house functioning would be to remove the hot and neutral that landed on breaker 7 at the panel from their lugs and cap them off individually, then connect the breaker 3 feed to the LINE side and the former breaker 7 feed to the LOAD side of the new GFCI.  Having the owner follow up on the situation would be highly recommended, though, as the extra load may cause some tripping of breaker 3 from simple overload of the circuit.

You'll also want to test the GFCI to make sure it's protecting what you expect it to; if the GFCI-protected loads turn out to be on breaker 3, then you'll have to reverse LINE and LOAD on the GFCI, and interchange the roles of the breaker 3 and breaker 7 homeruns in the panel as well.  Note also that this assumes breaker 3 and breaker 7 have the same amp rating; if they don't, then that throws an additional wrench into the works.

Comment: fortunately breaker 3 and 7 are on the same leg... or there would have been a dead shot on 240V until one or both breaker tripped. I wonder if the old GFCI  use to be two individual circuits or a 240V circuit  with a proper dual pole breaker on different poles, and something go changed in the past.  not surprised the GFCI failed with its load tied up this way.  @threephaseeel why do you recommend tying the LOAD side of the GFCI to the old breaker 7 feeder wires  should he just leave them off till he can figure out why it was wired this way?

Comment: @markf -- I'm making an educated guess that the stuff that stopped working was on the breaker 7 side of the GFCI

Comment: @3PhaseEEL when 7 tripped,  and with your set up it would now be powered from the LOAD of the outside GFCI.... ok  OP will have to confirm; but sounds reasonable (and not un-safe so long as 7 is disconnected at the panel)...

Comment: Doing this from my phone so if i can figure out how to add an jmage and then can find an image that matches the situation ill add that. The biggest issue atm is that everything other than the one and only outdoor plug was working until it got switched now the outdoor plug is working and the other stuff is not and i cant go back for more accurate details for a few days to a week goal is to get everything else at the minimum working when i do